# Error While Adding New Provider in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

When i try to add a new provider to my existing ionic project it throws

```
The generate command is only available for projects t
hat use ionic-angular >= 3.0.0
```

I tried the following command to upgrade but it doesn't worked out

```
>npm install --save ionic-angular
```

My Ionic Version is 3.2.0

My Package.json looks

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "~0.5.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^2.3.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.4",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "uuid": "^2.0.2",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  }
```

Comment: can you add your package.json?

Comment: yeah. you are using ionic 2.. if you want to shift to 3 then check this [package.json](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json) . Check the [changelog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: you can add your provider manualy creating the files